# Spring Boot Actuator Change the format of /health

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Recently I update spring-boot-starter-actuator to 2.2.2 and when I consume the `/health` endpoint i got:

```
{
    "groups": [],
    "status": {
        "code": "UP",
        "description": ""
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    "status": "UP"
}
```

And i don't have any clue the reason of this. Any idea? Or how I can refomat the output json to the original format? Not overwrite the HealthIndicator, only reformat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Actuator 2.2 [Health Endpoint JSON](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#health-endpoint-json) documentation says:

> The `/actuator/health` endpoint has changed the resulting JSON format by
>   renaming `details` to `components` for the first-level elements. This
>   helps to differentiate the actual details returned by a
>   `HealthIndicator` from the component indicators that make up composite
>   health.
>
> As a result of the change, the actuator media type has been bumped
>   from `application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json` to
>   `application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json`. If you have tools that
>   need to consume the older format, you can use an HTTP Accept: header
>   with the V2 media type, `application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json`.

In addition if you want to see all documentation related to `health` and what is `groups` ? how to custom the `health indicator` take a look the 
[Current Health Information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-health)

Comment: Thanks! But will there be any way to transform the new format for the old one?

Comment: I found the root of my problem. I created a @ControllerAdvice to create a JSONP structure that my project needed and it was this component that interfered with the actuator response